# Error when DeserializeObject to Datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, nhibernate, json.net, postman

I'm trying to convert a JSON string to DateTime by getting the date from headers, and encountering an error.

My code:

```
if (actionContext.Request.Headers.Contains("DataSync"))
{
    var date = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("DataSync").First();
    userRequest.LastSync =
        JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(date,new IsoDateTimeConverter());
}
```

Error:

```
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Error reading date. Unexpected token: Integer. Path '', line 1, position 2.",
"ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException",
"StackTrace": " em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsDateTimeInternal()\ \ em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReader reader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)\ \ em Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)\ \ em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)\ \ em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\ \ em Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value, JsonSerializerSettings settings)\ \ em Portal.Infraestructure.Filters.UserRequestFilter.OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) na d:\\Projetos\\api\\Portal\\Infraestructure\\Filters\\UserRequestFilter.cs:linha 28\ \ em System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.OnActionExecutingAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\ \ --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\ \ em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\ \ em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\ \ em System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\ \ --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\ \ em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\ \ em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\ \ em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\ \ em System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\ \ --- Fim do rastreamento de pilha do local anterior onde a exceção foi gerada ---\ \ em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\ \ em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\ \ em System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()\ \ em System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

I am using postman for testing. I am calling my controller and passing the date in headers on postman.[image]
What can i do for fix this error?

Comment: Logging `date` value may help...

Comment: Have you tried `JavaScriptDateTimeConverter` ?

Comment: This is a WebService and on application I will get the date from my database, this date will be my last syncronization.

Comment: Yes @JonKittel i tried, but got diferent error, Unexpected token or value when parsing date. Token: Integer, Value: 10. Path '', line 1, position 2."

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Solution:**

Use `DateTime.Parse()`

Comment: Very poor answer, it's a shame the poster accepted this answer as correct. Your answer should include more explanation and details including a small code sample which illustrates the solution and/or links to documentation.

Comment: The "Principal Software Engineer" dit not understend? I can explain for you @tpartee.

Comment: I never said I didn't understand, I said it's a poor answer by StackOverflow standards. Your answer is not useful for other engineers to help them understand the issue or enlighten them concerning the reasoning. This is a community system with standards you should be following. Your snarkiness goes a long ways to show that you don't give a damn about the community and are just out to grab reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe using a datetime format will do the trick.

```
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy"; 
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = format };

var ld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DateTime>(json,      dateTimeConverter);
```

Comment: Nope. Got the same erro.
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Unexpected token parsing date. Expected String, got Integer. Path '', line 1, position 2.",
"ExceptionType": "Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException",

Comment: @PedroFranco please also include date variable value to see if it's a valid JSON string or not...

Comment: I am taking the date from my Headers, as in the photo shared from postman.